# How to build a matrix one column at a time

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am wanting to build some matrices one column at a time, with columns from an existing matrix, as per the code below.

```
# x is an existing matrix, y is an array, pos_classes is a set

for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] in pos_classes:
        x_pos = np.append(x_pos, x[i])
        y_pos_actual = np.append(y_pos_actual, y[i])
    else:
        x_neg =  np.append(x_neg, x[i])
        y_neg_actual = np.append(y_neg_actual, y[i])
```

My question is, what should I initialise `x_pos` and `x_neg` as so that each `x[i]` gets appended column-wise? I tried as below, and each append turns `x_pos` into a 1D array.

```
x_pos = np.empty((0,x.shape[1]))
```

I'm fairly new to python and am probably missing something obvious.

Comment: It would probably be easier to do one row at a time. Why would you need one column at a time?

Comment: I have a dataset where each instance is a column in the matrix. I need to split the dataset up into two groups of instances. I want to avoid having to transpose the matrix all the time as it is an expensive operation

Comment: Although, if I did need to do it one row at a time, how would I initialise the empty matrix `x_pos` that gets appended to each iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. It's almost always better to do such things in a vectorized way in numpy.

First, build your index array `y_pos_actual`. Then, simply do

```
x_pos = x[:, y_pos_actual]
```

This will select all columns given by the indices `y_pos_actual` into a new matrix `x_pos`. You can do the same row-wise using

```
x_pos = x[y_pos_actual, :]
```